# Do servlet filters have to be specified in the web.xml file?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, servlet-filters

My company has a servlet filter we would like to include in various 3rd party Java web applications.  There is some hesitancy to edit the vendor's web.xml file.  Is this hesitancy warranted?  Is there another way to do this?   The app servers in question are Tomcat and Weblogix...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using Servlet API up to version 2.5 - there is no other way if you want portability - you must include the `Filter` in web.xml.

If using Servlet API 3.0, you can use `web-fragment.xml` inside your jar, or `@WebFilter` annotation on the filter, and it will automatically be deployed (the web-app should only specify `metadata-complete="false"` in order to include declarations from other modules)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, they have to go in the web.xml. Your hesitancy is warranted - I never like this kind of modification because it makes it very hard to incorporate vendor upgrades. But I'm not sure you have a choice. Just make sure your black-box/acceptance testing is robust enough to detect when your filter has got dropped during an upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.

I have been able to do this programmatically ([in Jetty](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletHandler.html) see addFilter() method), but this is a specific Jetty class, therefore I am not aware of a non-container specific way to get around this, so to be sure you code deploys across both Tomcat and Jetty, your approach is the only safe way.